# Almost retracting a ball to its boundary

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, retraction

One cannot continuously retract a closed ball $B_n$ to it boundary $S_n$, that is one cannot find a continuous map $f:B_n\to S_n$ such that $f|_{S_n} = \mathrm{id}_{S_n}$. What if we drop the latter condition and allow $f$ to move points on $S_n$ yet be onto?

Comment: Are you asking simply if there are continuous surjective functions $D^n\to S^n$? If this is question, the answer is easily yes

Comment: @arnett that's the question

Comment: I also wonder, which details or context is missing from this question?

Comment: I also think you mean $D^n \to S^{n-1}$, since the boundary of $D^n$ is $S^{n-1}$ and not $S^n$. But anyway you can project $D^n$ on a copy of $D^{n-1}$ seen as $D^n \cap \{x_n=0\}$ and then you have an homeomorphism $D^{n-1}/\partial D^{n-1} \cong S^{n-1}$, so a surjective continuous map $D^{n-1} \to S^{n-1}$. Compose the two maps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about the ball in $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Let $f(re^{i\theta})=e^{2ri\theta}$ for $\theta\in[0,\pi]$ and $f(re^{i\theta})=e^{(4\pi-2\theta)ri}$ for $\theta\in[\pi,2\pi]$, where $0\leq r\leq 1$.

**EDIT:** The intuition is that, on the circle $S_1$, the map is what you get by adding a path going round the circle once and its inverse in the fundamental group. Then use the shrinking radius $r$ to shrink the path down to being constant.

In fact, by using $\pi_n(S_n)\neq0$, you can apply this method to $B_n$ for any $n$.

Comment: Are you sure this is continuous for $\theta=\pi$? And how is this defined in $0$?

Comment: @arnett definition fixed